# Scala.Either getOrElse method

Tags: scala, either

Why when I type this all works fine?

```
Right(2).left getOrElse Right(4).left getOrElse Left("Error")
```

but when I type this compilation fails?

```
Right[String, Int](2).left getOrElse Right[String, Int](4).left getOrElse Left[String, Int]("Error")
```

Compilation error:

> value getOrElse is not a member of java.io.Serializable
>   println(RightString, Int.left getOrElse RightString,
>   Int.left getOrElse LeftString, Int)

So I can't chain `getOrElse` method call

Comment: This looks like a particularly obscure way to get fairly straightforward fallthrough behavior. Why not just write it differently instead of trying to shoehorn your desired behavior into those methods?

Answer (score 8):

The signature of `getOrElse` for a `LeftProjection[A, B]` is:

```
def getOrElse[AA >: A](or: ⇒ AA): AA
```

i.e. it expects the argument to be of some type `AA` which is a supertype of `A`.

In the first example, you left out type annotations, allowing the compiler to infer `Nothing` for `A`. Then, you supplied an argument of type `LeftProjection[Nothing, Int]`.

Because `Nothing` is a subtype of *all types*, `LeftProjection[Nothing, Int]` is trivially a supertype! This special case in the type system means that it type-checked almost by accident.

However, the most specific common supertype of `String` and `LeftProjection[String, Int]` is `Serializable`.

---

So, if you want to chain `Either`s, you need a method which can take another `Either[A, B]`, not just an `A` or `B`.

The method you seem to want would look like this:

```
def leftOrElse[A, B](e1: Either[A, B], e2: => Either[A, B]): Either[A,B] =
  e1 match {
    case Left(a) => Left(a)
    case Right(b) => e2
  }
```

(You could similarly write `rightOrElse`, which is a more common use case.)

This becomes syntactically a bit more usable if you make it an extension method, using implicits.

```
implicit class EitherOps[A, B](e1: Either[A, B]) {
  def leftOrElse(e2: => Either[A, B]): Either[A,B] = // as above
}
```

Because this expects `Either[A, B]` for both operands, instead of `A` or `B` (or some supertype thereof), you can chain your `Either`s.

```
scala> Right[String, Int](2) leftOrElse Right[String, Int](4) leftOrElse Left[String, Int]("Error")
res1: Either[String,Int] = Left(Error)
```